# My new Discord.Attachment() is not working It is showing an error in my discord.js bot

Tags: discord

```
} else if (msg.content === '?_saifz test') {
      const attachment = new Discord.Attachment('https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.CK95Aog4xZCaWVHnAr61pwHaHa?w=183&h=183&c=7&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7') // the problem
      msg.channel.send(attachment)
    }
    })
    keepAlive()
    client.login(process.env.lolUCannotGetToken)
```

I didn't put the other command because they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a valid image file type. You'll need to find a link to an image with a valid extension such as `.jpg`, `.png` or `.jpeg`.

Also, in order to prevent issues with the site taking the image down from their servers, I suggest you download the image to your project, so it's there forever.